# Monthwise average mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|  id  | C_Br | C_Date     | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|   1  | 51   | 2007-01-01 |        100         |
|   2  | 52   | 2007-01-01 |        100         |
|   3  | 53   | 2007-01-01 |        100         |
|   3  | 54   | 2007-01-01 |        100         |
|   4  | 51   | 2007-01-02 |        220         |
|   5  | 52   | 2007-01-02 |        300         |
|   5  | 53   | 2007-01-02 |        350         |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

I am trying to calculate per date average with below query:

```
SELECT Month(C_Date) as Date,avg(daily_typing_pages) 
FROM tbl_data 
GROUP BY C_Br,Month(C_Date)
```

But rather than dividing it by no of days in a month it is also dividing with count of C_Br.
Is there any solution to calculate monthly average (Assuming sum of total daily_typing_pages per day as one unit)

Comment: Typically, if a column appears in the GROUP BY, then it makes sense for it to appear in the SELECT. For anything else, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please take not that only grouping by `MONTH` does not look at the `YEAR`, probably not giving you the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Month(C_Date) as Date,sum(daily_typing_pages)/DAY(LAST_DAY(max(C_Date))) 
FROM tbl_data 
GROUP BY C_Br,Month(C_Date)
```

Date wise avg()

```
SELECT C_Date as Date,avg(daily_typing_pages) as AVG
FROM tbl_data 
GROUP BY C_Date;
```

Comment: #1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Comment: can you add your expected output??

Comment: Suppose on every date there are 4 branches(C_Br) and 100 daily typing pages for each C_Br throughout the month.

 I want to treat all the branches in a particulars day as one unit and as output i want that system displays average 400 for whole month, but actual output after using avg function it is 100.

Answer (score 0):

You should try for average month and year, so here is the query.

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(t.`C_Date`), '-', MONTH(t.`C_Date`)) AS ym, AVG(t.`daily_typing_pages`) 
FROM tbl_data t
WHERE 1
GROUP BY ym
```

`ym` is year and month, which I used for grouping results and calculating average.